# Overclocking Q6600 ...doesn't work

Tags: cpu, motherboard, overclocking

Maybe this is a really generic question but I found no answer, and Q6600 *is* a really popular CPU.

I've tried the HOWTOs on Google, all the stuff I could find.

However, once I set some higher FSB (can't set spread spectrum.. it won't let me), the PC won't boot, have to reset bios. I could set the CPU voltage to +0.125 ..but with only that, I'm at the same place just with more voltage.

Here is my [mainboard](http://eu.msi.com/index.php?func=proddesc&prod_no=1373&maincat_no=1&cat2_no=170&cat3_no=2)

Comment: What's processor stepping ?

Comment: Stepping: G0 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If even the slightest overclocking does not work, maybe you have a buggy BIOS version.

On some boards you may need to disable SpeedStep to achieve stable overclocking (which unfortunately results in higher CPU temperature); however, my ABIT IP35 Pro does not have this problem ;)

Also try to decrease RAM frequency before trying to set higher FSB — increasing the FSB frequency without switching the FSB:RAM ratio may push RAM over its limit (especially if using some cheap RAM).

Overclocking Q6600 with a box cooler is also problematic due to overheating issues, but this usually results in instability under load, not in a completely unbootable system.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try to look around. It's got a Zalman CNPS9700 cooler on it, and its about 25-40C depending on the room temperature. Under load, 40-60C.